# Why doesn't this SQL query work on Northwind database?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Find the total number of cities the customers come from.

```
select count(*)
from 
(select distinct city
from customers);
```

Error:

> Error line 4: Incorrect syntax near ')'..

what is the explanation?

Comment: You need to add alias to subquery `select count(*)
from 
(select distinct city
from customers) AS s;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your previous questions I assume you use `Oracle` where you can write:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT 1 FROM dual)
```

but not:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT 1 FROM dual) AS s
-- ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

But in `SQL Server` you need to add alias to subquery:

```
select count(*) from (select distinct city from customers) AS s;
```

[FROM clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177634.aspx):

> [AS] table_alias
>
> When a derived table, rowset or table-valued function, or operator
>   clause (such as PIVOT or UNPIVOT) is used, **the required table_alias** at
>   the end of the clause is the associated table name for all columns,
>   including grouping columns, returned.

`SQL Server` force you to add alias for column expression and aggregated columns:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT 1) AS s
-- No column name was specified for column 1 of 's'.
```

And you need to use:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT 1) AS s(c)

SELECT *
FROM (SELECT 1 AS c) AS s
```

---

Personally I am not fan of subqueries and I prefer common table expressions syntax:

```
;WITH cte(city) AS
(
  SELECT DISTINCT city 
  FROM customers
) 
SELECT COUNT(*) AS no_of_cities
FROM cte;
```

Of course for such easy query the best approach is to add `DISTINCT` directly to `COUNT`:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT city) AS no_of_cities
FROM customers;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to assign an alias when using the subquery:

```
select count(*)
from 
(select distinct city
from customers) as MyTable;
```

Or just skip the subquery, in this example:

```
select count(distinct city)
from 
customers;
```